Why am I getting a 500 error when sending emails using Resend in my Next.js API route?
I'm building a Next.js application where I'm trying to send emails using the Resend service within an API route. However, I keep encountering a 500 error, and I'm not sure what's causing it. Below are the details:
app/api/send/route.ts
import { Resend } from "resend";
import { MeetingRequest } from "@/api/email-templates/MeetingRequest";

const resend = new Resend(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RESEND_KEY);

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const {
    to_email,
    receiver_name,
    scheduler_id,
    scheduler_name,
    scheduled_time,
    scheduler_tz,
    question_title,
    question_id,
    sender_note,
  } = await request.json();

  try {
    const { data, error } = await resend.emails.send({
      from: "Codey from CodingOH <codey@codingoh.com>",
      to: [to_email],
      subject: `You received a meeting request from ${scheduler_name}!`,
      react: MeetingRequest({
        receiver_name,
        scheduler_id,
        scheduler_name,
        scheduled_time,
        scheduler_tz,
        question_title,
        question_id,
        sender_note,
      }),
    });

    if (error) {
      console.error("[UP] Error sending email:", error);
      return Response.json({ error }, { status: 500 });
    }

    return Response.json({ data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("[DOWN] Error sending email:", error);
    return Response.json({ error }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

app/questions/[id]/route.tsx
const response = await fetch("/api/send", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    to_email: question.asker?.email_address ?? "",
    receiver_name: question.asker?.first_name ?? "",
    scheduler_id: coder?.auth_id ?? "",
    scheduler_name: `${coder?.first_name} ${coder?.last_name}`,
    scheduled_time: formattedDate?.toISOString() ?? "",
    scheduler_tz: coder?.timezone ?? "",
    question_title: question.question ?? "",
    question_id: question.id ?? 0,
    sender_note: scheduleMessage || "",
  }),
});
if (!response.ok) {
  console.error(
    "Error sending meeting request email:",
    await response.text()
  );
} else {
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log("Meeting request email sent:", data);
}

api/email-templates/MeetingRequest.tsx
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { FaCode } from "react-icons/fa6";
import { parseISO, format } from "date-fns";
import { toZonedTime } from "date-fns-tz";

export const MeetingRequest = (props: {
  receiver_name: string;
  scheduler_id: string;
  scheduler_name: string;
  scheduled_time: string;
  scheduler_tz: string;
  question_title: string;
  question_id: number;
  sender_note: string;
}) => {
  const {
    receiver_name,
    scheduler_id,
    scheduler_name,
    scheduled_time,
    scheduler_tz,
    question_title,
    question_id,
    sender_note,
  } = props;

  const date = parseISO(scheduled_time);
  const zonedDate = toZonedTime(date, scheduler_tz);
  const formattedDate = format(zonedDate, "MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' h:mm a");

  return (
    <main className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center bg-slate-200">
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center w-full py-2 bg-slate-300">
        <Link href="https://codingoh.com" className="flex flex-row items-center ml-[10px]">
          <FaCode className="text-3xl" />
          <div className="flex flex-col">
            <span className="text-2xl text-blue-700 font-bold ml-2">CodingOH</span>
            <span className="text-[10.5px] ml-2">Stack Overflow in Real Time</span>
          </div>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-2 w-full p-2 bg-white text-sm">
        <p>Hi {receiver_name},</p>
        <p>
          <Link href={`https://codingoh.com/users/${scheduler_id}`} className="text-blue-500 hover:underline">
            {scheduler_name}
          </Link> 
          has requested a meeting with you on 
          <span className="font-bold underline">{formattedDate}</span>.
          Specically, {scheduler_name.split(" ")[0]} wants to help you out with
          this question:{" "}
          <Link href={`https://codingoh.com/questions/${question_id}`} className="text-blue-500 hover:underline">
            {question_title}
          </Link>.
        </p>
        {sender_note && (
          <div className="bg-slate-300 p-2 rounded-md">
            <p className="font-semibold">Sender Note</p>
            <p>{sender_note}</p>
          </div>
        )}
        <p>
          You can choose to <span className="text-green-500">accept</span>, 
          <span className="text-red-500">reject</span>, or 
          <span className="text-blue-500">reschedule</span> the meeting. If you
          plan on rescheduling the meeting to another time, let 
          {scheduler_name.split(" ")[0]} know what time you would like it
          scheduled at. Make sure to include your time zone to avert confusion
          about the starting time.
        </p>
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center w-full">
          <Link href={`https://codingoh.com/questions/${question_id}`} className="p-2 bg-blue-600 text-white rounded-md">
            Check Out the Meeting Request
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Best,</p>
          <p className="flex flex-row items-center gap-1 text-blue-700 font-bold">
            CodingOH <FaCode />
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

GitHub Repo: https://github.com/jesuschrist-immanuel/stack-overflow-clone
When I make the POST request, I get a 500 error and the response returns {"error":{}}. I suspect this might be an issue with how I'm using the resend.emails.send method, but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot further.
Things I've tried:

Verified that the NEXT_PUBLIC_RESEND_KEY is correctly set.
Ensured that all required fields in the email template are being passed correctly.
Checked console logs, but the error object is empty.

Any guidance or assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Does it work if you pass JSX ‘react: ’

@pip36 - The Resend docs state that the React template works with the Node SDK.  https://resend.com/docs/send-with-nextjs
